# Error in table after update

Tags: tables

The next MWE caused no errors last time computed (1 or 2 years ago); recently, on updating packages, it gives me an `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` error. Any advice is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{sectsty} \deffootnote{1.8em}{1.6em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{0.25\textwidth}>{\centering}m{0.05\textwidth}>{\raggedright}m{0.25\textwidth}>{\centering}m{0.05\textwidth}>{\raggedright}m{0.25\textwidth}}
{>}{>}~\texttt{help} & & & & \\
& & & & \\
{>}{>}~\texttt{exit} & & & &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need (have always needed) `\arraybackslash` after `\raggedright` or `\centering` in the last column. (you have tagged this tabularx but your example does not use tabularx at all)

Comment: You can also use `\tabularnewline` instead of \\ at the end of the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either

- change all instances of `>{\raggedright}m` and `>{\centering}m` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m` and `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m`, respectively, or
- load the [ragged2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package and replace all instances of `>{\raggedright}m` and `>{\centering}m` with `>{\RaggedRight}m` and `>{\Centering}m`, respectively.

Technically, it's only the final column's definition that needs to be adjusted along the lines of the preceding bullet points. However, I think it's excellent practice to add `\arraybackslash` to all type-`p` and type-`m` column definitions.

Naturally, you could also follow @F.Pantigny's advice and replace `\\` with `\tabularnewline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% new:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,makecell,tabularx,sectsty}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\deffootnote{1.8em}{1.6em{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.25\textwidth}
   >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.05\textwidth}
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.25\textwidth}
   >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.05\textwidth}  
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.25\textwidth}}
 
 {>}{>} \texttt{help} & & & & \\[1\baselineskip]
 {>}{>} \texttt{exit} & & & &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```